# Calculate derivative diff() and keep length - add NA

Tags: r

How can I calculate the numeric derivative of a column in a data frame (with diff()) 
and keep the length by adding NA values?

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking.  Keep the length of what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39485948/90580) to a question of mine.

If you were looking for a generic way to prepend `NA`

```
pad  <- function(x, n) {
    len.diff <- n - length(x)
    c(rep(NA, len.diff), x) 
} 

x <- 1:10
dif <- pad(diff(x, lag=1), length(x))
```

but if you are not afraid to bring in `zoo` library **it's better to do**:

```
library(zoo)
x <- 1:5
as.vector(diff(zoo(x), na.pad=TRUE)) # convert x to zoo first, then diff (that invokes zoo's diff which takes a na.pad=TRUE)
# NA 1 1 1 1 (same length as original x vector)
```

Answer (score 14):

Its unclear where exactly you want NA's, but you can concat them right in.

```
 dif <- c(NA, diff(dfrm$id, lag=1))
```