# How can I pad a vector with NA from the front?

Tags: r

I want to make an existing vector size `n` and use `NA`. I know I can pad at the end of the vector like so:

```
v1 <- 1:10
v2 <- diff(v1)
length(v2) <- length(v1)
v2
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 NA
```

But I want to fill the `NA` at the beginnning instead in a **generic** way. I mean for this particular example I can just

```
v2 <- c(NA, diff(v1))
# NA 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

But I was hoping that there exist some base R function or library that provides something like `v2 <- pad(v2, n=length(v1), value=NA)`

Is there anything like that I can use off the self or do I need to define my own function:

```
pad  <- function(x, n) { # ugly function that doesn't keep the attributes of x
    len.diff <- n - length(x)
    c(rep(NA, len.diff), x) 
}

pad(1:10, 12) # NA NA 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: I don't think your function is ugly by any means.

Comment: I don't think your function is ugly either.  why not set n=1 and then you've solved your problem.

Comment: For `NA` padding you could also use `v1 <- 1:10; v2 <- diff(v1); length(v2) <- length(v1); v2[order(!is.na(v2))]`

Comment: Maybe not ugly, but I rather use some existing base R / library instead (if they exist).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `v1` has the desired length and `v2` is shorter (or the same length) these left pad `v2` with `NA` values to the length of `v1`.  The first four assume numeric vectors although they can be modified to also work more generally by replacing `NA*v1` in the code with `rep(NA, length(v1))`.

```
replace(NA * v1, seq(to = length(v1), length = length(v2)), v2)

rev(replace(NA * v1, seq_along(v2), rev(v2)))

replace(NA * v1, seq_along(v2) + length(v1) - length(v2), v2)

tail(c(NA * v1, v2), length(v1))

c(rep(NA, length(v1) - length(v2)), v2)
```

The fourth is the shortest.  The first two and fourth do not involve any explicit arithmetic calculations other than multiplying `v1` with `NA` values.  The second is likely slow since it involves two applications of `rev`.

Answer (score 6):

One option is `diff` from `zoo` which also have the `na.pad`

```
library(zoo)
as.vector(diff(zoo(v1), na.pad=TRUE))
#[1] NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: This is perfect in my example since I'm doing a diff but It doesn't answer the more general problem of padding an existing vector `v2` to have same size as `v1`. (imagine that I wasn't  using `diff()` in the first place)

Comment: @ecerulm  Your function is also good.  Another variation is  `c(rep(NA, sum(is.na("length<-"(v2, length(v1))))), v2)`

Answer (score 1):

Defining nrValues as the number of elements you want at the start of v2 you could use:

`n <- length(v1)
v2 <- c(rep(NA,nrValues),v1[nrValues:n])`

I'm not familiar with a function that does this, so if you intend to do it multiple times I would create your own function.