# R Filling missing values with NA for a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, na

I am currently trying to create a data-frame with the following lists

```
location <- list("USA","Singapore","UK")
organization <- list("Microsoft","University of London","Boeing","Apple")
person <- list()
date <- list("1989","2001","2018")
Jobs <- list("CEO","Chairman","VP of sales","General Manager","Director")
```

When I try and create a data-frame I get the (obvious) error that the lengths of the lists are not equal. I want to find a way to either make the lists the same length, or fill the missing data-frame entries with "NA". After doing some searching I have not been able to find a solution

Comment: How do you plan on these lining up? What dates correspond to what jobs, etc?

Comment: Assuming you want the NAs to be at the end, I'd use a similar solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485869/how-can-i-pad-a-vector-with-na-from-the-front) with a fixed n

Comment: @camille for the sake of this example the lining up doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
data.frame(sapply(dyem_list, "length<-", max(lengths(dyem_list))))

   location         organization person date            Jobs
1       USA            Microsoft   NULL 1989             CEO
2 Singapore University of London   NULL 2001        Chairman
3        UK               Boeing   NULL 2018     VP of sales
4      NULL                Apple   NULL NULL General Manager
5      NULL                 NULL   NULL NULL        Director
```

Where `dyem_list` is the following:

```
dyem_list <- list(
  location = list("USA","Singapore","UK"),
  organization = list("Microsoft","University of London","Boeing","Apple"),
  person = list(),
  date = list("1989","2001","2018"),
  Jobs = list("CEO","Chairman","VP of sales","General Manager","Director")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are `purrr` (part of `tidyverse`) and base R solutions, assuming you just want to fill remaining values in each list with `NA`. I'm taking the maximum length of any list as `len`, then for each list doing `rep(NA)` for the difference between the length of *that* list and the maximum length of *any* list.

```r
library(tidyverse)

location <- list("USA","Singapore","UK")
organization <- list("Microsoft","University of London","Boeing","Apple")
person <- list()
date <- list("1989","2001","2018")
Jobs <- list("CEO","Chairman","VP of sales","General Manager","Director")

all_lists <- list(location, organization, person, date, Jobs)
len <- max(lengths(all_lists))
```

With `purrr::map_dfc`, you can map over the list of lists, tack on `NA`s as needed, convert to character vector, then get a data frame of all those vectors `cbind`ed in one piped call:

```r
map_dfc(all_lists, function(l) {
  c(l, rep(NA, len - length(l))) %>%
    as.character()
})
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   V1        V2                   V3    V4    V5             
#>   <chr>     <chr>                <chr> <chr> <chr>          
#> 1 USA       Microsoft            NA    1989  CEO            
#> 2 Singapore University of London NA    2001  Chairman       
#> 3 UK        Boeing               NA    2018  VP of sales    
#> 4 NA        Apple                NA    NA    General Manager
#> 5 NA        NA                   NA    NA    Director
```

In base R, you can `lapply` the same function across the list of lists, then use `Reduce` to `cbind` the resulting lists and convert it to a data frame. Takes two steps instead of `purrr`'s one:

```r
cols <- lapply(all_lists, function(l) c(l, rep(NA, len - length(l))))
as.data.frame(Reduce(cbind, cols, init = NULL))
#>          V1                   V2 V3   V4              V5
#> 1       USA            Microsoft NA 1989             CEO
#> 2 Singapore University of London NA 2001        Chairman
#> 3        UK               Boeing NA 2018     VP of sales
#> 4        NA                Apple NA   NA General Manager
#> 5        NA                   NA NA   NA        Director
```

For both of these, you can now set the names however you like.