# creating dataframe from a nested list

Tags: r

What is the optimum way for creating a data frame from a nested list.

```
#installing package
installed.packages("qdap")
#loading qdap package
library("qdap")

# Finding synonyms from the below function which gives a list.
data <- synonyms("power")

# Converting list to dataframe
plyr::ldply(data, cbind)

t(plyr::ldply(data, rbind))
```

At last, I would like to create multiple data frame. from the output of:

```
synonyms(c("taste","company","power"))
```

list output looks alike using dput()

```
structure(list(power.def_1 = c("ability", "capability", "capacity", 
"competence", "competency", "faculty", "potential"), power.def_2 = c("brawn", 
"energy", "force", "forcefulness", "intensity", "might", "muscle", 
"potency", "strength", "vigour", "weight"), power.def_3 = c("ascendancy", 
"authority", "bottom", "command", "control", "dominance", "domination", 
"dominion", "influence", "mastery", "rule", "sovereignty", "supremacy", 
"sway"), power.def_4 = c("authority", "authorization", "licence", 
"prerogative", "privilege", "right", "warrant")), .Names = c("power.def_1", 
"power.def_2", "power.def_3", "power.def_4"))
```

Comment: Please post list data using `dput()`.

Comment: everyone that wants to help you needs to install it, which puts me off from answering questions like that.

Comment: ok so let me share the structure with you...

Comment: @PoGibas i've included the list structure for your reference. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: hence the headers for dataframe could be ("power.def_1", 
"power.def_2", "power.def_3", "power.def_4")

Comment: it's not a nested list, it's just a list, but the elements don't have equal length, what data frame would you expect as an output ? filled with NAs when not enough elements ?

Comment: so i am unable to post nested list output here due to restrictions of stackoverflow, post executing synonyms(c("taste","company","power")), we can see the output in nested list

Comment: yes, filled with NA's is fine

Comment: you'd like to put each of these power.def in a data.frame and bind them all vertically ?

Comment: so the ouput should look alike: power.def_1(column1) and its values than power.def_2(column2)...so on

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper correct.

Comment: duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044812/r-filling-missing-values-with-na-for-a-data-frame/51047625#51047625

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Filling missing values with NA for a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044812/r-filling-missing-values-with-na-for-a-data-frame)

Comment: @snoram i hope you got the question correctly which is for creating mutliple dataframes using lisst.

Comment: Ok. probably not. Would be best if you were clearer about input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Would it work like this ?

```
lapply(l, function(li)
  data.frame(lapply(li,'length<-',max(lengths(li)))))

# [[1]]
# power.def_1  power.def_2 power.def_3   power.def_4
# 1      ability        brawn  ascendancy     authority
# 2   capability       energy   authority authorization
# 3     capacity        force      bottom       licence
# 4   competence forcefulness     command   prerogative
# 5   competency    intensity     control     privilege
# 6      faculty        might   dominance         right
# 7    potential       muscle  domination       warrant
# 8         <NA>      potency    dominion          <NA>
# 9         <NA>     strength   influence          <NA>
# 10        <NA>       vigour     mastery          <NA>
# 11        <NA>       weight        rule          <NA>
# 12        <NA>         <NA> sovereignty          <NA>
# 13        <NA>         <NA>   supremacy          <NA>
# 14        <NA>         <NA>        sway          <NA>

...
```

More compact using `purrr` :

```
library(purrr)
map(l,~map_dfc(.,`length<-`,max(lengths(.))))
```

**data**

```
l1 <- structure(list(power.def_1 = c("ability", "capability", "capacity", 
                                    "competence", "competency", "faculty", "potential"), power.def_2 = c("brawn", 
                                                                                                         "energy", "force", "forcefulness", "intensity", "might", "muscle", 
                                                                                                         "potency", "strength", "vigour", "weight"), power.def_3 = c("ascendancy", 
                                                                                                                                                                     "authority", "bottom", "command", "control", "dominance", "domination", 
                                                                                                                                                                     "dominion", "influence", "mastery", "rule", "sovereignty", "supremacy", 
                                                                                                                                                                     "sway"), power.def_4 = c("authority", "authorization", "licence", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "prerogative", "privilege", "right", "warrant")), .Names = c("power.def_1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "power.def_2", "power.def_3", "power.def_4"))

l <- list(l1,l1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help here, however for every sublist i would like to create a different data frame instead of rowbind. sorry if i was not clear at the beginning.however got some hint from your solution.

Comment: so if you just remove the `do.call(rbind,` you get what you want ?

Comment: correct, and running the nested list in a loop by assigning n no of dataframes

Comment: I updated my answer to remove the row binding, I don't understand your last comment though and cannot install the qdap package. If you need futher help please elaborate.