# create table based on list of outputted values

Tags: r

I am running multiple outlier analysis. I want to organize the outliers into a table. Here is some sample data and code.

```
library(Routliers)
res <- outliers_mcd(x = data.frame(CR_metrics_1[-1]), h = .75, alpha = .05)
res$outliers_pos
 23  24  25  32  37  58 

res <- outliers_mcd(x = data.frame(CR_metrics_2[-1]), h = .75, alpha = .05)
res$outliers_pos
 23  4  10  32  15  59
```

I want it to look something like this:

```
Out_analysis_1    Out_analysis_2
23                     23 
24                     4
25                     10
32                     32
37                     15
58                     59
```

I'm not sure how to do this. I tried this, but that's just giving me to 2 numeric vectors.

```
x <-  23  24  25  32  37  58 
y <-  23  4  10  32  15  59
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. You need to assign the output to vectors, and then use the vectors to make a new dataframe.

```
res <- outliers_mcd(x = data.frame(CR_metrics_1[-1]), h = .75, alpha = .05)
Out_analysis_1<-res$outliers_pos

res <- outliers_mcd(x = data.frame(CR_metrics_2[-1]), h = .75, alpha = .05)
Out_analysis_2<-res$outliers_pos

df<-data.frame(Out_analysis_1,Out_analysis_2)
```

If it turns out the vector are of different lengths, then you will want to find the max length of the vectors and pad the shorter vectors with NAs.

```
maxlength=max(length(Out_analysis_1),length(Out_analysis_2)

length(Out_analysis_1) <- length(maxlength)
length(Out_analysis_2) <- length(maxlength)
#included both, since not sure which one is longer)
```

Comment: Thank you, Joe! I am getting an error message about there being a different number of rows: "Error in data.frame(x, y) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 56, 54." I uploaded a portion of my data, not the entire thing. I am looking up how to get around this. Do you have thoughts about dealing with this error?

Comment: You can either trim the first vector using Out_analysis_1<-res$outliers_pos %>%  head(54) or add 2 elements to the last vector using Out_analysis_2<-res$outliers_pos %>% append(c(0,0))

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: I will want to combine multiple dfs and I am wondering if it makes more sense to add in code indicating to fill the empty cells.

Comment: You are getting the error because normally dataframes have columns with equal numbers of rows. So you can pad the 2nd column, or shorten the first one. You can either trim the first vector using Out_analysis_1<-res$outliers_pos %>%  head(54) or add 2 elements to the last vector using Out_analysis_2<-res$outliers_pos %>% append(c(NA,NA)). Probably best to pad with NAs, rather than zeros as i described above. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485869/how-can-i-pad-a-vector-with-na-from-the-front which talks about padding vectors

Comment: That makes sense, Joe. Thank you! If I were to try to merge multiple dfs at the same time with different lengths, is there I way I could modify your code to make this work? I think I can do this using plyr and rbind.fill, but am not sure. This is what I was reading: https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/01/23/r-combining-vectors-or-data-frames-of-unequal-length-into-one-data-frame/