# Adding new column with diff() function when there is one less row in R

Tags: r, diff

If I have a sample data frame like mtcars, and I want to find the difference between mtcars$qsec for all rows, I can do diff(mtcars$qsec).  But is there a simple way to make diff(mtcars$qsec) a new column in the original mtcars data frame?  I'm finding it difficult because there's one less row in diff(mtcars$qsec) than the rest of mtcars.

```
> head(mtcars,3)

               mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710    22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Comment: N numbers means N-1 diffs. There are a few different ways to make a length N vector out of N-1 values, eh. Usually, `c(NA, diff(x))` or similar.

Comment: Maybe a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13594021/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate derivative diff() and keep length - add NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594021/calculate-derivative-diff-and-keep-length-add-na)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two approaches.  Both put an `NA` in the first row of `diff_qsec` and put `diff(qsec)` in the remaining rows:

```
library(dplyr)  
mtcars %>% mutate(diff_qsec = qsec - lag(qsec)) # dplyr has its own version of lag

transform(mtcars, diff_qsec = c(NA, diff(qsec)))
```

Also, on the general issue of padding see: [How can I pad a vector with NA from the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485869/how-can-i-pad-a-vector-with-na-from-the-front/39495520#39495520)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the base function within() like so:

```
mtcars <- within(mtcars, difference <- c(NA,diff(qsec)))
```

This creates a column called "difference" with the first element NA and the rest calculated by diff(qsec).

You could create more columns at the same time by wrapping commands in {}, such as:

```
mtcars <- within(mtcars, {difference <- c(NA,diff(qsec))
                         multiple <- qsec*2})
```

Note that you must use <- for the assignment and not =.

Comment: Can you just add the column as you would normally with offset? mtcars$dmpg<-c(NA,diff(mtcars$mpg))